# Excel, create an automatic save/change log, how to?

Tags: vba, excel, logging, save

I teach at a university and one assignment i have developed tests some quite specific modelling skill sets in Excel. Because of this, and because all assignments need to be fairly weighted, they end up having largely the same content (in terms of the final code) with different variables so that they are not exact copies - so it is fairly easy for students to take another persons completed file and input their own variables, change a few cosmetic items (drag data locations, colours, borders etc) and hand the work in as their own. i am confident that this is occurring and most of the time i can identify the suspects easily but proving the collusion (not so much detecting it), this is difficult.

I am trying to work out how i can include somewhere on the worksheet (which i will provide as a template) a function that logs the user ID and time each incidence that the save button is pressed (or at a set interval)? This way i can have this info logged in the background (hopefully where nobody can find or goes looking for it) and it will be quite easy for me to see if at any point along the way the student working on the sheet changed - indicating collusion. Of course there are other ways around this, and i am not looking for a fail safe system, just an easy way to catch lazy cheats.

I can find functions that save the last user to a cell, but none that can provide an ongoing log. Ideally, i would like it to be as covert as possible, i.e., avoiding obvious macros would be handy but i can understand this might be a problem. Does anyone have any tricks up their sleeve to help me in my quest to wipe out student copying?

Comment: "avoiding obvious macros" What is an obvious macro as opposed to a non-obvious one? Are your student writing VBA code or just editing worksheet contents manually? Are you just looking to password-protect the VBA project? If you want to increase your chances of getting help, you'll have to reduce the length of your question text to the essentials, and clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve, and preferably show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Type sign in Excel's help. Look at digital signatures. There may be some way of using them?

From Help

After you have installed your digital certificate, you can sign files and macro projects.

When you digitally sign a file, you certify that the information in the file is valid and that it has not been modified since the file was signed. As long as a file is unchanged, reviewers can attach signatures to it. You might use a digital signature with important files. When you digitally sign a macro project, your digital signature says that you guarantee that the project is safe. Just as signed files remain signed until the file is modified, signed macro projects remain signed until the macro code is altered.

Or perhaps turn on track changes and make an initial change yourself.